# Colouring faces depending on their normal direction in VTK (python)

Tags: python, vtk

I would like to visualize an object from an `STL` file in `VTK` which is not a problem.

However, I would also like to highlight certain faces and colour them differently than the main object depending on the threshold angle value between their normals and arbitrarily chosen direction, say `z = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. Say, all faces which form less than `45 degrees` angle to the `z-direction` should be coloured in red.

I managed to do this using `trimesh` module, but it takes too much time to draw the object.
Is there an elegant way to do this using `VTK` module?

Here is my code so far:

```
import vtk
import numpy as np
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy, numpy_to_vtk

filename = "out.stl"
reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)

normals = vtk.vtkPPolyDataNormals()
normals.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
normals.ComputeCellNormalsOn()
normals.ComputePointNormalsOff()
normals.ConsistencyOn()
normals.AutoOrientNormalsOn()
normals.Update()

cellNormals = vtk_to_numpy(normals.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetNormals())

angle = numpy_to_vtk(np.arccos(np.dot(cellNormals, (0.0,0.0,1.0))))
normals.GetOutput().GetCellData().SetScalars(angle)

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 1)

# Create a rendering window and renderer
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderingwindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderingwindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Create a renderwindowinteractor
renderwindowinteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderwindowinteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderingwindow)

# Assign actor to the renderer
renderer.AddActor(actor)

# Enable user interface interactor
renderwindowinteractor.Initialize()
renderingwindow.Render()
renderwindowinteractor.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [vtkPolyDataNormals](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataNormals.html) to compute the normals - make sure you have ComputeCellNormalsOn.

Next, you need something to loop over the normals and compute the dot product to your test direction. Since you're in Python, I suggest using vtk_to_numpy on the normals array, and doing it in numpy.

```
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy, numpy_to_vtk
pd = polyDataNormals.GetOutput()
cellNormals = vtk_to_numpy(pd.GetCellData().GetNormals())
angle = numpy_to_vtk(np.arccos(np.dot(cellNormals, testNormal)))
pd.GetCellData().SetScalars(angle)
```

Now, you can use the color mapping features of vtkPolyDataMapper to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I indeed use `vtkPPolyDataNormals`.But I do not understand how to set the colour to a certain face?

Comment: Cell coloring example in python: https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Visualization/AssignColorsCellFromLUT